# print 1st string of a line if last 5 strings match input

Tags: bash, awk, ksh, gawk

I have a requirement to print the first string of a line if last 5 strings match specific input.

Example: Specified input is `2`

```
India;1;2;3;4;5;6
Japan;1;2;2;2;2;2
China;2;2;2;2
England;2;2;2;2;2
```

Expected Output:

```
Japan
England
```

As you can see, `China` is excluded as it doesn't meet the requirement (last 5 digits have to be matched with the input).

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?  This should be possible within a few minutes of bringing up the Awk manual for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep ';2;2;2;2;2$' file | cut -d';' -f1
```

- `$` in a regex stands for "end of line", so grep will print all the lines that end in the given string
- `-d';'` tells cut to delimit columns by semicolons
- `-f1` outputs the first column

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n 's/^\([^;]*\).*;2;2;2;2;2$/\1/p' file
```

It captures and output non `;` first characters in lines ending with `;2;2;2;2;2`

It can be shortened with GNU sed to:

```
sed -nE 's/^([^;]*).*(;2){5}$/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk -F';' -v v="2" -v count=5 '
   {
     c=0;
     for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i == v) c++ 
        if(c>=count){print $1;next}
     }
   }' file
```

where

- `v` is the value to match
- `count` is the maximum number of value to print the wanted string
- the `for` loop is parsing all fields delimited with a `;` in order to find a match

This script doesn't need the 5 values `2` to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\; '/;2;2;2;2;2$/{print $1}' file
Japan
England
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.